# Count wins and losses for each team in a league

Tags: python

Here is the problem.

*Repeatedly ask the user to enter game scores in a format like team1 score1 - team2 score2. Store this information in a dictionary where the keys are the team names and the values are tuples of the form (wins, losses).*

Here is my Solution, what can I change for the better in it?

```
number_of_games = int(input("Enter the total number of Games: "))
team_wins_and_loses = {}
for _ in range(number_of_games):
  team1, score1, __, team2, score2 = input("Enter the game results(Note that the name of the team must be a single word, without spaces):").split()
  team1_result, team2_result = ((1, 0), (0, 1)) if int(score1) > int(score2) else ((0, 1), (1, 0))
  if team1 not in team_wins_and_loses:
    team_wins_and_loses[team1] = team1_result
  else:
    updated_result = (team_wins_and_loses[team1][0] + team1_result[0], team_wins_and_loses[team1][1] + team1_result[1])
    team_wins_and_loses[team1] = updated_result

  if team2 not in team_wins_and_loses:
    team_wins_and_loses[team2] = team2_result
  else:
    updated_result = (team_wins_and_loses[team2][0] + team2_result[0], team_wins_and_loses[team2][1] + team2_result[1])
    team_wins_and_loses[team2] = updated_result
  print(team_wins_and_loses)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Please always use 4 spaces to indent when using Python.
2. Rather than the verbose name `team_wins_and_loses` we could use `team_results`.
3. Rather than adding both values of the tuple we should focus on adding 1 win to the winning team, and 1 lose to the losing team.

   ```py
   winner[0] += 1
   loser[1] += 1
   ```
4. We can change your turnery to pick the wining or losing team, and then extract the value with the correct default.

   ```py
   winning_team, losing_team = (
       (team1, team2)
       if int(score1) > int(score2) else
       (team2, team1)
   )
   if winning_team not in team_results:
       winner = team_results[winning_team] = [0, 0]
   else:
       winner = team_results[winning_team]
   # same for losing team
   ```
5. We can use `dict.setdefault` to remove the need for the if.

   ```py
   winner = team_results.setdefault(winning_team, [0, 0])
   ```
6. We can use `collections.defaultdict` to make interacting with `team_results` much cleaner, rather than using `dict.setdefault`.

   ```py
   def default_scores():
       return [0, 0]

   team_results = collections.defaultdict(default_scores)
   # ...
   team_results[winning_team][0] += 1
   ```

```py
import collections


def default_scores():
    return [0, 0]


team_results = collections.defaultdict(default_scores)
number_of_games = int(input("Enter the total number of Games: "))
for _ in range(number_of_games):
    team1, score1, __, team2, score2 = input("Enter the game results(Note that the name of the team must be a single word, without spaces):").split()
    winner, loser = (
        (team1, team2)
        if int(score1) > int(score2) else
        (team2, team1)
    )
    team_results[winner][0] += 1
    team_results[loser][1] += 1
    print(team_results)
```

Answer (score 3):

**add_tuples**

Since you need `tuple[int, int] + tuple[int, int]` multiple times, I'd put it into a simple function. This will make the rest of your code more concise and readable.

```
def add_tuples(tuple1: tuple[int, int], tuple2: tuple[int, int]):
    return tuple1[0] + tuple2[0], tuple1[1] + tuple2[1]
```

---

**collections.defaultdict**

This is a perfect use case for a `defaultdict`. Instead of manually checking if a team already exists as a key in `team_wins_and_losses`, we can let `defaultdict` handle that for us.

```
from collections import defaultdict
team_wins_and_losses = defaultdict(lambda: (0, 0))
```

This will give us a `defaultdict` that inserts the tuple `(0, 0)` anytime we try to call a non-existent key for the first time.

*Why the lambda?* `defaultdict` expects a callable as an argument, which returns the desired default value without taking any arguments. I don't currently know of a better way to achieve this for tuples.

---

**Tied games**

Your code currently handles everything that isn't a win for team1 as a win for team2. The problem statement does not explicitly specify ho to handle ties, so I would just skip tie games completely:

```
if score1 == score2:
    continue
```

---

**Complete code**

I made some other small changes (including corrected spelling) that should be pretty straightforward and added clarifying comments where necessary. Feel free to ask for further information if needed.

```
from collections import defaultdict


def add_tuples(tuple1: tuple[int, int], tuple2: tuple[int, int]):
    return tuple1[0] + tuple2[0], tuple1[1] + tuple2[1]


number_of_games = int(input("Enter the total number of games: "))

# Moved this message to only print once instead of on every line
print("Note that the team names must be a single word, without spaces")

team_wins_and_losses = defaultdict(lambda: (0, 0))

for _ in range(number_of_games):
    team1, score1, _, team2, score2 = input("Enter game results: ").split()

    # Tied game
    if score1 == score2:
        continue

    # I find this to be more readable than the one-liner
    if int(score1) > int(score2):
        team1_result, team2_result = (1, 0), (0, 1)
    else:
        team1_result, team2_result = (0, 1), (1, 0)

    # We can now concisely update the team scores
    team_wins_and_losses[team1] = add_tuples(team_wins_and_losses[team1], team1_result)
    team_wins_and_losses[team2] = add_tuples(team_wins_and_losses[team2], team2_result)


# If you want to print this as a regular dict you can simply cast it to a dict
# dict(team_wins_and_losses)
# Generally not necessary though, as defaultdict provides the same functionalities
print(team_wins_and_losses)
```